# CodeIgniter jQuery Drag and Drop Re-Order Data Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, codeigniter

I am trying to create a draggable list in CodeIgniter using jQuery. I have the code so that the dragging works, but I can't get the data to go to the controller.

This is the jQuery code for dragging.

```
$(function() {

        $( "#order" ).sortable({
            opacity: 0.6,
            cursor: 'move',

            update: function(event, ui){
 var order = $(this).sortable("serialize");
 console.log(order);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/codeigniter214/profile/save_order",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: order,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#test").html(data);
                    }    
                });
                }    
            });    
});
```

This is the draggable list.

```
<?php if (isset($names)) {?>
<ul id="order">
    <?php foreach (array_combine($ids, $names) as $id => $name) {?>
    <li id="feed-<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $name; ?> <a href="profile/removefeed/<?php echo $id ?>">Remove</a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

This is the controller that the data is being passed to. However, the var_dump shows an empty array which leads me to believe the issue is with the AJAX and information transfer.

```
function save_order() {
var_dump($_POST);

    $items = $this->input->post('item');
    $total_items = count($this->input->post('item'));

    echo '<h3>Debugging</h3>';
    echo "<p>Total items sent: $total_items</p>";

    $this->profile_model->update_order($total_items, $items);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being about CodeIgniter's CSRF implementation. Ended up changing the jQuery to what is below and used jQuery Cookie to set a cookie.

```
$(function() {

$( "#order" ).sortable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    cursor: 'move',
    update: function(event, ui){
        var order = 'csrf_test_name=' + $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name') + '&';
        order += $(this).sortable("serialize");
        console.log(order);
        $.ajax({
            data: order,
            csrf_test_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name'),
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://127.0.0.1/codeigniter214/profile/save_order",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#test").html(data);
            }

        });
    }

});
});
```